# angular2 , Tour of Heroes , ngmodule imports

Tags: angular

I'm trying practice use Ngmodule and imports, so I moved this line:
(from heroes.component.ts file)
         import { Hero } from './hero';

to app.module.ts  file:

```
    import { Hero } from './hero';
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
         BrowserModule,
         FormsModule,
         routing,
         Hero
        ],
```

but i get this error:

```
[0] app/heroes.component.ts(20,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Hero'
```

It's possible to let in the components just the basic import:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
and move all the rest imports to NgModule? or have I restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are restrictions to what should be included inside an NgModule. Esentially a module groups together a set of functionality, you can only add components, directives, services and other modules to an NgModule, your hero import should be inside a component, not a module.

```
import { Hero } from './hero';
//This import should stay inside app.component.ts
```

So your files would be

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<p>A template goes in here</p>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public hero: Hero;
}
```

And:

```
//app.module.ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ], //other modules you require
  declarations: [ AppComponent ], //declares components and directives
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ] //your root component
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: thanks; have a doubt yet, service go to 'providers:' in NgModule;  from component the import line move to the app.module.ts and the directives from @ Component decorator to 'declarations:' in NgModule, but wha exactly go th the 'imports:' in NgModule? never a personal component?

Comment: when you move a service, you must to keep the import line for the file service, in the component?  and in the NgModule file;  the import line and the 'providers:'?

Comment: No, in the 'imports' you only import other modules like the BrowserModule or your own. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: And yes, you need to declare your service twice for a healthy data flow.

Answer (score 1):

The reason  that propery 'imports' in NgModule is not for import components but to import another modules (files where another NgModules , grouped by another components  ).

Components can be moved to Ngmodule in 'imports:' property:
the import line: import {  } from '..'; and 'directives' line

Service can be moved to NgModule in 'providers:' property 
but the difference it's that service must to keep in the component the: import {  } from '..';

Comment: Excellent! Now you have solved your own question. Keep learning!